# Why do we want transition maps of an atlas to be differentiable

Tags: differential-geometry

In my view the transition maps provide a correspondence between different coordinates for the same point of a manifold with respect to two different charts.

Why do we need these to be differentiable necessarily? which is beyond the properties of the chart being only a homeomorphism.

Comment: Quick answer: because you want to do differential calculus.

Comment: @user10354138 well yea, but that is to broad of an answer for me tho. I am looking for a more concrete situation where we need this.

Comment: To ban cases like a cone sewn to a sphere.

Comment: Because when you want to study differential properties of the manifold, you want to use the things you already know for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and study the problem in a chart; if the transition maps are not differentiable, then those properties might be chart-dependent.

Comment: @dcolazin that sounds intersting, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}$.  With the usual identity chart the notion of being differentiable agrees with what we have classically.  With a non-differentiable transition the situation changes, e.g., in the chart $\varphi(x)=x^3$ (transition function $x^{1/3}$ not differentiable at $0$), differentiability now imposes a growth constraint $f(x)=f(0)+O(x^3)$ with respect to the original chart, not something you want.  More weird example can be formed with other charts such as $1+C$, $C$ the Cantor function.

Comment: @user10354138 smoothness is required of the compotision $x \cdot y^{-1}$. Are you suggesting looking at the atlas where both $x^{3}$ and $x$ are charts? Because $x^{3}$ also composite its inverse is indeed smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $f:M \rightarrow N$, and you want to define its differential $d_pf$. The differential of a diffeomorphism should be invertible everywhere and the identity (between the same atlas) should be a diffeomorphism.

If we allow non-differentiable transition functions, then consider $N=M = \mathbb{R}$ with an atlas containing the charts $x$ and $x^3$. The differential should be "functorial", so we should be able to read it on charts. If on $M$ we use the $x$ chart and on $N$ the $x^3$ chart, then the identity on $M$ is the function $x \rightarrow x^3$ that has a non-invertible differential in $0$.

Comment: The identity does not need to be an diffeomorphsim not even if one has N=M

Comment: @user1 why do you think so?

Comment: thats precisely the defintion of "different differentiable structures"

Comment: @user1 I'm considering $M=N$ in the "$\mathcal{C}^\infty$" category when you admit non-differentiable transitions, so $M,N$ have the same (not only diffeomorphic) structure (aka if $M=N$, not only $M \cong N$, then the identity is a diffeomorphism).

Comment: Basically we just consider the identity map between manifolds with same differential structure? I find the first sentence kind of confusing in that case, is it really relevant?

Comment: @user1 yes, the idea is: if we merge together non-compatible atlas, then we can't calculate things; I'll try to improve the sentence